# Were some of the hostages taken by Hamas killed in cross-fire by Israeli forces?

Tags: israel, palestine, israel-hamas-war

In this [widely watched interview with *Middle East Eye*](https://youtu.be/rTQcjyhPOIk?si=RqVCIfKVwfSgKtEe), Yasmin Porat describes being kidnapped from a kibbutz by Hamas (translation provided by Middle East Eye):

> Yasmin Porat: We shouted at that point to the special forces who had gotten there to stop shooting, and they heard me and they stopped. And I saw on the grass of the kibbutz there, five or six hostages lying on the ground outside, from the massacre, in the line of fire between our forces and the terrorists
>
> Aryeh Golan (Interviewer): The terrorists shot at them?
>
> YP: No. They were wounded in the exchange of fire. There was heavy firing going on.
>
> AG: So they could have been shot by our own forces while they were trying to eliminate kidnappers?
>
> YP: Absolutely. It's painful for me, they fired on everyone there, including the hostages.

Is the translation accurate? Are there corroborating accounts?

Comment: Are you asking if they killed hostages? If that is the case it isn't what the question title is suggesting.

Comment: @JoeW she says "hostages" though probably not the ones taken to Gaxa..Anyway, I have changes it to avoid that confusion

Comment: I am strongly tempted to close this as [a current event](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/handling-news-questions-about-current-events/2870). It seems unlikely we will get better evidence for some time.

Comment: @Oddthinking With your edit the question makes a lot more sense and I do agree about it being a current event that will be hard to get accurate information about.

Comment: BTW, the same report says she saw tank fire on the kibbutz houses. I find that believable given some of the aftermath pictures. And the lack of reports about Hamas fighters blowing themselves up on this occasion. Unless they had absolutely crystal clear intel, tank fire could have easily killed some hostages inside the houses.

Comment: Some photos from Be'eri show half-demolished houses, which would have required a fair bit of explosive power, probably not possible with RPGs that Hamas were spotted carrying too. https://www.reuters.com/resizer/mUHUeQMe6QGsNraC8cnt-_NvQnY=/1200x0/filters:quality(80)/cloudfront-us-east-2.images.arcpublishing.com/reuters/DPRQR3VTERJQZPW22PJUDQU5JY.jpg ; https://www.reuters.com/resizer/l3jE0BDUlvr4A1cHu0LIlUZ5ZJg=/1200x0/filters:quality(80)/cloudfront-us-east-2.images.arcpublishing.com/reuters/2JGQUVOF4FPDZCINLIVY7PCBFE.jpg

Comment: It's worth noting that even the original claim doesn't present it as a verified fact...AG prompts YP with speculation about whether it's possible, and YP admits it was in fact possible, in a way that indicates that he himself believes it.  Nobody is claiming to know exactly where each bullet came from, unless something was lost in translation.

Comment: @Fizz: You say it is believable but in politics.SE you [wrote it is ridiculous?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/82323/26878)

Comment: @C.F.G: The claim there is **most** people were killed by the IDF. Your objection is unreasonable.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes.

TRT World with the following title: [Israel's army helicopter hits Israeli festivalgoers during Hamas attack — report](https://www.trtworld.com/middle-east/idf-helicopter-hits-israeli-festivalgoers-during-hamas-attack-report-15887735) reported that:

> The [Haaretz newspaper](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-11-18/ty-article/.premium/israeli-security-establishment-hamas-likely-didnt-have-prior-knowledge-of-nova-festival/0000018b-e2ee-d168-a3ef-f7fe8ca20000) said on Saturday an Israeli security assessment was based on an investigation by police with Hamas fighters who were arrested on October 7.
>
> Haaretz reported that the military helicopter arrived at the site of the festival and **opened fire on the fighters but also wounded several festival participants.**
>
> It said, according to the assessment, the gunmen had no prior information about the festival which was held close to the Kibbutz Re'im, near the borders with Gaza.

Middle East Monitor shared an interview with Israeli pilot Nof Erez: [Israeli Colonel Nof Erez discusses October 7 operation and the Hannibal Directive](https://www.middleeastmonitor.com/20231121-israeli-colonel-nof-erez-discusses-the-unexpected-large-scale-of-the-october-7-operation-and-the-deployment-of-the-hannibal-directive/). (see also on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkjRqAJYDUg))

According to Erez, the **[Hannibal Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannibal_Directive)**, which Israel is believed to have suspended in 2016, was formulated by the Israeli army 30 years ago based on events in Lebanon.

> "The Hannibal Protocol is intentional, and if the decision was made to implement it, it is carried out intentionally. If the captives were unintentionally shot, that's another matter," the pilot said on the October 7 attack, when Hamas fighters infiltrated areas surrounding the strip, including the festival near the settlement of Re'im.

Erez said that on that day, it is unknown whether Israeli warplanes and drones hit hostages while firing. He said

> "The Hannibal (Protocol), for which we have been running drills for the past 20 years, concerns a single vehicle with hostages in it. You know which part of the fence it goes through, which way on the road it heads to, and even which route it takes,".
>
> "What we’ve seen here is mass Hannibal. There were many gaps in the fences. There were thousands of people in many different vehicles, both with and without hostages."

Erez, who coordinated a helicopter mission to evacuate wounded during Israel's ongoing attacks on Gaza, said

> "It was an impossible task to identify and do what was allowed."
>
> "I know that whoever held the weapons systems, both the drones and the fighter pilots, did whatever they could without coordinating with the ground forces, because these forces were not yet there."

### Update: December 14, 2023 -- Hadas Dagan Testimony

[Middle East Monitor on December 11, 2023 reported](https://www.middleeastmonitor.com/20231211-survivor-of-kibbutz-beeri-incident-reveals-harrowing-details-of-israeli-forces-assault/) (With the Video):

> **Hadas Dagan**, the only survivor of the Kibbutz Be’eri incident on 7 October, *has broken her silence*, recounting the horrific events. During the Israeli forces’ arrival, a fierce exchange of gunfire ensued, followed by missile strikes. Amidst this chaos, **Dagan recalls the children’s desperate screams for help. Her testimony brings to light the targeted assault on civilians by the Israeli army, including her partner Adi, who was killed in the attack**. Dagan vividly describes the terrifying moments, including her futile attempt to stem the bleeding from Adi’s wound, ultimately lying in a pool of blood beside him.

Comment: This entire answer furnishes nothing more than vague rumors, evidence-free. Even these rumors never mention anything about "killing," which is the claim.

Comment: @YouDontSay: What the pilot say is rumor??? Secondly, you want the official say that "Yes we killed them?"

Comment: pilot says, 'who knows'? This forum is about evidence, not guesses

Comment: While the "Hannibal Protocol" was for periods of time a semi-official order it was never executed in reality, and was canceled around 2016-2017

Comment: @Giacomo1968 That's "Jigsaw wasn't technically a murderer" type logic. If a terrorist takes a hostage, and someone shoots at the terrorist and hits the hostage, the hostage's death is cause by the terrorist, and the terrorist is morally and legally responsible for it.

Comment: @Acccumulation: Your argument is correct in your own terms "one vs one and on the ground" not when they are shooting with helicopters or tanks.

Comment: The source you provided is edited deceptively and edits out that the hostages were killed during a firefight between IDF forces and the terrorist. That before the shooting started, IDF soldiers tried to call for the surrender of the terrorists to save the lives of the hostages, even that the commander of the terrorists surrendered and called his subordinates to surrender as well but was answered with fire. And that Hamas terrorist continued to fire everything they had, small arms and RPG rockets. The interviewed never say that the killed were from IDF fire.

Comment: Cont. from last comment, the full video and interview are available here: https://www.mako.co.il/news-military/6361323ddea5a810/Article-f5fdaeb7aeb4c81027.htm

Comment: @SIMEL: She says the prisoners were inside the house, the tank fired two rockets and many were killed. Even if Hamas fired bullets or RPGs, it should hurt the Israeli soldiers, not the prisoners.

Comment: @C.F.G, you don't know if Hamas fired only at the soldiers or at the hostages as well, the original clip has recordings of the terrorists threatening to execute the hostages. Your sources edits out important parts of the video, not just take a single continuous clip, but cut out important context out. One clip they edited out is how the commander surrendered, he went out holding a civilian hostage as a shield and when she shouted "I'm a civilian, stop shooting" they stopped. The clip you provide: "Yamam forces fire two rockets at the house" without context...

Comment: @C.F.G cont. Actual video: Hamas terrorist continue to shoot non stop, IDF soldiers call them to surrender because there is real fear they will execute the hostages, Hasan (the commander) calls them to surrender but is answered with fire. Yamam forces fire two rockets at the house. Different context, different meaning of the IDF actions. (time stamp ~16:40 at original video).

Comment: @SIMEL: What does this line mean: "אני לא רוצה שמישהו ייקח את הסיפור עם הדילמה המאוד קשה שמונחת פה ויפנה אצבע מאשימה לצבא"/// What I understand is that she knows that the IDF is guilty for killing the hostages but even knowing this, she says that I don't want anyone to blame the IDF. I'm right?

Comment: @C.F.G more: at ~17:50: Yasmin watches the events from the side: "They are conducting some kind of negotiation with the megaphone, and time passes, and it starts to get dark, and they suddenly brought a tank. And I say to one of the soldiers: 'Tell me, but if you shoot shells, won't it hurt the hostages?' He said no, that they were just doing it on the sides to take down walls. But it was a crazy exchange of fire."
Adi, (Hadas's husband) is killed from a bullet wound. But she says it right after talking about the tank shooting.

Comment: @C.F.G again, this is only a partial quote: "It is clear that this event poses a very heavy moral dilemma," described Hadas. "I don't want anyone to take the story with the very difficult dilemma that lies here and point the finger of blame at the IDF. People there gave their lives to save us. I am also thankful to those who were there and fought for me." She doesn't say that the IDF is "guilty", she thinks that some of the hostages might have been killed by IDF fire, but she doesn't blame them for it and is thankful for their acts in an impossible situation forced on them by Hamas.

Comment: @C.F.G, just a small correction, I use IDF for short, but at this specific event IDF and Police forces were involved.